Difference between 何かしますか and 何をしますか
Between 何かしますか and 何をしますか, which one is correct grammatically?
Which one do native Japanese people use?

They are simply different phrases. 何かしますか is a colloquial form of 何かをしますか and

何か means something
何 means what

Thus

何か(を)しますか means Are you going to do something?
何をしますか means What are you going to do?

Both are natural by themselves. It depends on contexts which fits better.
